# How to write an E4X XML primitive to a new text/xml window in Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, xml, e4x

I'm writing a small browser-side Javascript that parses XML from a file and modifies it. The output ideally would be a .xml file, but of course making a JS client write files is nearly impossible so I gave up on that.

I want Firefox to open a new window of contentType text/xml, with my serialized xml in it:

```
var xmlDoc = new XML(SourceXMLString); //SourceXMLString is read from an xml text file
output = window.open("");
output.document.open("text/plain");
output.document.write(xmlDoc.toXMLString());
output.document.close();
```

However any document.write instance seems to set the contentType to text/html and so all the tags are rendered wrong, naturally. [From this fixed bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73409) it seems that document.open creates the right contentType but document.write messes it up.

- This only needs to work in Firefox 2+.
- Server-side is not an option.
- I went with Javascript & Mozilla because of ECMAScript for XML support.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to open a new tab with the XML:

```
open("data:application/xml," + encodeURIComponent(xmlDoc.toXMLString()));
```

If you want the user to be able to *download* the XML, use application/octet-stream instead of application/xml.